# Pass Collection of string to (String... values)

Tags: java, string, collections

I have a very simple question.

This below method-

`newColumnsPredicate`

takes input as `String... colNames`

Below is the method signature as well-

```
public static SlicePredicate newColumnsPredicate(String... colNames) {

   //Some code

}
```

And I have below `collection of strings` that I wanted to use in the above method-

`final Collection<String> attributeNames`

So I decide to use it something like this-

`newColumnsPredicate(attributeNames.toString());`

This is the right way to do this? As after I run my program, I don't get any data back so I am suspecting it might be possible the way I have added is wrong.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String... is a vararg parameter. It is used to indicate that the parameter should either be an array of Strings, or as many String arguments as you like.

Calling toString() on the collection will merely return one string that combines all of the Strings it contains.

You should instead write something that converts your collection to an array, and then pass that in, like:

```
attributeNames.toArray(new String[attributeNames.size ()])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What is this Foo here? I am not able to understand that. And what I should be using in my case?

Comment: Sorry, cut and paste error from some other code. I've replaced Foo with String.

Comment: How about this? `newColumnsPredicate((String[]) attributeNames.toArray())`. This should work right?

Comment: Yes, that would work, but it's best practice to pass an array of the correct size into the toArray() method. Doing so lets you avoid the cast, and the method is smart enough to use the array that you pass in if it is large enough to do so. If you follow the pattern in my answer, that will be the case.

Answer (score 0):

No, When you do a `attributeNames.toString()`, you are passing a single String to the method, with a square bracket around them, like `"[a, b, c]"`, Where as your program expects something like `"a", "b", "c"`.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the `toArray()`[function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28%29) be useful here?

```
public void test() {
    Collection<String> collection = new HashSet<>();
    newColumnsPredicate(collection.toArray(new String[collection.size()]));
}

public static SlicePredicate newColumnsPredicate(String... colNames) {
    //stuff
}
```

EDIT:
Whoops, didn't see the other guy answered in the same way.